# On what Stack Exchange site should I ask tech/platform questions like this one?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where should I ask this?

> I need some help making some tech choices, and I'm not sure where else
>   to turn.
>
> I realize answers to this question could be influenced by personal
>   opinion, but that's okay. I'm actually hoping to hear those opinions.
>
> **My challenge is this:**
>
> I am trying to develop a platform upon which non-engineers can produce
>   custom reports against transaction-level data. I have access to a data
>   team that maintains a data warehouse, which can be used to structure
>   data for said reports. The trick is, working out a platform that
>   supports the following criteria:
>
> **Primary Criteria**
>
> The data and presentation should be separate concerns. So, the report
>   builder would ideally not have to be terribly technical, and would
>   just be building a report template, if that makes sense.
>
> I should be able to email the report to a user as either a link to an online
>   report, or as a static "PDF" version of the report. The sending of
>   emails would be triggered by application-level events.
>
> **Secondary Criteria**
>
> It would be wonderful if the reports could also be executed in an
>   offline state. That is, without requiring an internet connection. For
>   example, a JavaScript-generated report with JSON data objects behind
>   it.
>
> An HTML-to-PDF generator that understands and honors bootstrap
>   styles, div elements, etc. That is, not having to write everything in
>   tables. I've used ABCPdf by webSupergoo and Aspose.Pdf, but both seem
>   to rely heavily on the use of tables, and struggle with bootstrap.

Comment: see also: [How can Stack Overflow help developers evaluate technologies?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305678/839601)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For software recommendations, for each of the components necessary for "trying to develop a platform" like the one you describe, I think you should use the [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange which

> is a question and answer site for people seeking specific software
>   recommendations.
>
> Good software recommendation requests have two components: a purpose
>   (a task to accomplish, a user story) and some objective requirements
>   (a minimum set of features). Please read our [question quality
>   guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) before asking for a recommendation.

Be sure to ask for only one recommendation per question.